# With Trello, Is it possible to transfer account to a different e-mail?

Tags: trello, account-management, backup

Is it possible to change the email address associated with a Trello account?

Alternatively, is it possible to back up a particular board to import to another account?

Answer (score 3):

The [change email feature/bugfix](https://trello.com/c/ceQBujqn) has been released.

You can change the email address associated with your account by going to https://trello.com/my/account

Answer (score 1):

<s>Not yet. I do believe though that they have it on there public board showing that it's one of the possible ideas to allow for importing/templates for boards, so eventually you will probably be able to do so, but not as of right now.</s>

You could send a feature request to their email at: `support@trello.com`

**Edit:** They have implemented the feature! See the other answer!

Comment: This feature has been implemented